# How to make flat buttons in webix

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, flat, webix

As far as I can tell, webix's default buttons looks like this:

[image]

[I saw in a demo](http://webix.com/demos/admin-app/#!/app/orders), however, "flat" type buttons like this:

[image]

How do I go about making my navigation buttons look like that? I do not see anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: are you importing `webix.css`?

Comment: I am not, just style.css and the CSS for a skin

Comment: I'll replace the photo with the result from webix.css

Comment: That image of the demo you posted might be of the accordion component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component on screenshoot is a Tree actually.

In common case, you may use "menu" or "list"

```
{ view:"menu", layout:"y", select:true, width:150, data:[
  "Firts",
  "Second",
  "Third"
]},
```

http://webix.com/snippet/07fa93b6

Comment: Thanks. Menu seems to be close enough to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a [Accordion](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__accordion.html) component

**UPDATE**

From looking at the demo it appears it might be the [Tree](http://docs.webix.com/datatree__index.html) component. The classes of the elemnts have tree in the name